# Redirects for main domain are being triggered for sub domains

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, subdomain, apache2

I have a domain configured on my server to redirect all requests to the HTTPS version of my site which is all working fine. A few days back, I added a sub-domain which is now being redirected to the main domain as well. Here's the config files for the apache so far.

1. httpd.conf (System generated, not edited by me)

   ```
   <VirtualHost my.ip:80>
       ServerName bwdmedia.net
       ServerAlias bestwebsitedesigners.in bestwebsitedesigners.net bwdmedia.co bwdmedia.org www.bestwebsitedesigners.in www.bestwebsitedesigners.net www.bwdmedia.co www.$
       DocumentRoot /home/bwdmedia/public_html
       ServerAdmin webmaster@bwdmedia.net
       UseCanonicalName Off
       CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/bwdmedia.net combined
       CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/bwdmedia.net-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
       ## User bwdmedia # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
       UserDir enabled bwdmedia
       <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
           suPHP_UserGroup bwdmedia bwdmedia
       </IfModule>
       <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
           <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
               SuexecUserGroup bwdmedia bwdmedia
           </IfModule>
       </IfModule>
       <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
           RMode config
           RUidGid bwdmedia bwdmedia
       </IfModule>
       <IfModule itk.c>
           # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
           #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
           AssignUserID bwdmedia bwdmedia
       </IfModule>

       ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/bwdmedia/public_html/cgi-bin/








       Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/bwdmedia/*.conf"
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost my.ip:80>
       ServerName crm.bwdmedia.net
       ServerAlias www.crm.bwdmedia.net
       DocumentRoot /home/bwdmedia/public_html/crm
       ServerAdmin webmaster@crm.bwdmedia.net
       UseCanonicalName Off
       CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/crm.bwdmedia.net combined
       CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/crm.bwdmedia.net-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
       ## User bwdmedia # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
       UserDir enabled bwdmedia
       <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
           suPHP_UserGroup bwdmedia bwdmedia
       </IfModule>
       <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
           <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
               SuexecUserGroup bwdmedia bwdmedia
           </IfModule>
       </IfModule>
       <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
           RMode config
           RUidGid bwdmedia bwdmedia
       </IfModule>
       <IfModule itk.c>
           # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
           #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
           AssignUserID bwdmedia bwdmedia
       </IfModule>

       ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/bwdmedia/public_html/crm/cgi-bin/




       Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/bwdmedia/*.conf"
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. cp_php_magic_include_path.conf (The include file at the end of previous VirtualHost

   ```
   ServerName www.bwdmedia.net
   ServerAlias bwdmedia.co bwdmedia.org www.bwdmedia.co www.bwdmedia.org bwdmedia.net
   Redirect 301 "/" "https://bwdmedia.net/"
   ```

I'm trying to access `crm.bwdmedia.net` but get redirected to `https://bwdmedia.net`. If I comment out the 3 lines in Point 2, the subdomain starts working. So somewhere here is the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: add your subdomain under "ServerAlias"

Comment: But then wouldn't I be instructing it to redirect it for the subdomain? I need something of a negative alias, or exception list.

Comment: It looks like you are redirecting all trafic to that virtualhost. So adding your subdomain.domain.tldr should solve this.

Comment: The traffic gets to this virtualhost because of the IP which stays the same. Then the servername and alias decide where the files for that domain are.  I forgot to add the virtualhost of `crm.bwdmedia.net`, now added to the question. Please check. Note that both these containers are including the same file at the end.

Comment: And you have restarted httpd?

Comment: Yes. I do that after every change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48099/discussion-between-orphans-and-veek).

Answer (score 1):

Use a RewriteCond to match domains other than example.com and 301 redirect them:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If the domain (any domain) is not exactly example.com...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

You can also look more specifically for subdomains of example.com. The one above would match any other domain.

```
# Match only subdomains of example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```